# Update a label within the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that looks like this:

```
function recalculateWhatIfCurrentRate(aEle, aChangedLabel, recordID, yearEndCurrentRate) {
    var rate = document.getElementById(aEle).value;
    document.getElementById(aChangedLabel).value = yearEndCurrentRate * (1 + rate);
}

aEle = ctl00_cpMain_tbCurrentRatePercentIncrease_131578
aChangedLabel = ctl00_cpMain_lblScrollCurrentRate_131578
recordId = 131578
yearEndCurrentRate = 100.65
```

I want to change the actual text of `aChangedLabel`.

Why doesn't it change in the DOM?

Comment: Try using "innerHTML" instead of "value" for your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label tags don't have a value attribute, you need to set innerHTML to change the text.

Answer (score 2):

`<label>` elements don't have `value` properties, they are standard container elements. Their text content will be represented as TextNodes amongst their children (or descendants).

Answer (score 0):

Values pulled out of the DOM are **strings** by default. This is probably failing in the calculation, because you can't do math with strings.

Try converting the value to a number:

```
var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById(aEle).value);
```

Comment: Javascript _usually_ converts strings to numbers on the fly when a number is needed instead of a string. The one you should be aware of is if you are trying to do addition, then it does matter because you might just concatenate instead.